# How to make user controls know about css classes in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, css, visual-studio-2008, user-controls

Since there are no header sections for user controls in asp.net, user controls have no way of knowing about stylesheet files. So css classes in the user controls are not recognized by visual studio and produces warnings. How can I make a user control know that it will relate to a css class, so if it is warning me about a non-existing css class, it means that the class really do not exist?

Edit: Or should I go for a different design like exposing css classes as properties like "HeaderStyle-CssClass" of GridView?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Here's what I did:

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Stylesheet.css" id="style" runat="server" visible="false" />
```

It fools Visual Studio into thinking you've added a stylesheet to the page but it doesn't get rendered.

---

Here's an even more concise way to do this with multiple references;

```
<% if (false) { %>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Stylesheet.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.2.6.js" />
<% } %>
```

As seen in [this blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/21/combining-jquery-form-validation-and-ajax-submission-with-asp.net.aspx) from Phil Haack.

Comment: @blachawk `if (false)` means it will never be executed, the code is there purely as a hint to VS.

Answer (score 3):

Add the style on your usercontrol and import css in it.

```
 <%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="WCReportCalendar.ascx.vb"
Inherits="Intra.WCReportCalender" %>
 <style type='text/css'>    
      @import url("path of file.css");
       // This is how i used jqueryui css
      @import url("http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css");               

 </style>

 your html
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating composite UserControl, then you can set the [CSSClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass.aspx) property on the child controls..

If not, then you need to expose properties that are either of the [Style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass.aspx) type, or (as I often do) string properties that apply CSS at the render type (i.e. take them properties and add a *style* attribute to the HTML tags when rendering).

Comment: Should the Style link be pointing to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.style.aspx ?

Answer (score -4):

You Can use `CSS` direct in `userControl`.

Use this in `UserControl`:

```
 <head>
    <title></title> 
    <style type="text/css">
      .wrapper {
          margin: 0 auto -142px; 
         /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */ 
       }
    </style>
 </head>
```

This will work.

Comment: This means that you would have to have CSS duplicated in each ascx file, which is bad in many ways.

Comment: No you can use this usercontrol in MasterFile.Then there is no need to write this in each file

Comment: You can also attach stylesheet in usercontrol as given below. <head>
<title></title> 
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Stylesheet.css" id="style" runat="server" /></head>

Comment: Yes, you can put a reference to to the UserControl in the MasterPage, but the question is asking about how to make the UserControl recognize that a CSS rule exists in a separate .css file.

Comment: You can also attach stylesheet in usercontrol as given below. <head> <title></title> <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Stylesheet.css" id="style" runat="server" /></head>