# How can I specify a *.css file in an ASP.NET UserControl?

Tags: .net, asp.net, css, user-controls, stylesheet

I have a CSS file that contains all of the `<style>` tags for my website.

How can I link it to my UserControl so I can use the styles in the `CssClass` attributes for my child conrols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this thread -> [How to make user controls know about css classes in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34390/how-to-make-user-controls-know-about-css-classes-in-asp-net)